# jquery highlight row based on specific column's value

Tags: jquery, highlight

Using jQuery, I would like to highlight all rows, where the second column contains the `-` character.

Here are the details of the second column...

1. The second column's header (th) is "Due In"
2. The values in the second column are strings
3. There isn't a specific class for the second column

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The `2nd` in Lucas' answer does not work for me in jquery 1.4, but this does:

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(1):contains(-)').parent().css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr td:eq(1):contains('-')").parent().addClass("highlight");
```

@recursive : I changed the selector for the "eq", thanks.

Comment: this works but only highlights the first row to match this criteria.  How do I repeat for each row?